# Regression Specification and Relation to Conditional Expectation Function

Tags: regression, conditional-expectation

In their book, [Mostly Harmless Econometrics](http://www.mostlyharmlesseconometrics.com/), Angrist & Pischke introduce regression as an approximation to the conditional expectation function (CEF). They present (p 46) this equation:

$$E[(Y_i-X’_i\beta)^2|X_i]=Var[Y_i|X_i]+(E[Y_i|X_i]-X’_i\beta)^2$$

In words, the conditional mean of the squared residuals equals the conditional variance of the dependent variable plus the square of the gap between the CEF and the regression line.

> ***Question***: What is the relation, if any, between the following:
>
> (a) A regression model being correctly specified;
>
> (b) The absence of any gap between the regression line and the CEF?

When thinking of correct specification in terms of a model's functional form (e.g. whether linear or double-log) it seems plausible to identify (a) and (b).  However, I suspect there may be complications regarding:

1. The choice of independent variables, both of the model, and in respect of which variables a CEF is conditional upon.
2. Whether in considering any gap we are comparing the CEF with a population or with sample data.

Can anyone give a definitive statement of the relationship between (a) and (b)?

*Note: I have edited this question having seen [this question on Meta](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2685/a-difficulty-with-self-study-like-questions-of-the-form-is-this-correct) which perhaps indicates why the original received no answer.*

Comment: I think this is a really good question because I have it too. My professor mentioned a similar statement in his lecture notes, namely that the model being well specified implies the equality with the conditional expectation.